# Gnome3-like alternatives

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome3

Since I discovered gnome3-shell I really appreciated the different Dekstop-type to work with, and I'm still using it.

But, I'm battery-addict (using a laptop) and I'm feeling poor performances and less support with Gnome3, consuming too resources, such as long loadings of little programs and some laggy animations, the Arandr that resets to default everytime the layout for the dual-monitor, and the plug-ins that are no more developed. So my question is: is there a Gnome3-like DE solution? or what would you suggest for me?

I am using the Gnome-shell because I like the multiple and dynamic multi-desktop creation 
and easy managing of multiple monitors without any configuration-writing. Also, I tried KDE once, but it is pretty hard to understand the usage, and I had some graphic glithces.

Comment: Are you using GNOME3 Classic Mode or the GNOME Shell? Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Probably the smoothest experience I've had with Arch Linux is `enlightenment`. It's easy, very lightweight, and pretty good looking to boot. `pacman -S enlightenment ; enlightenment-start` will get you going in most cases.

Comment: reply with this exact comment,and i'll set your answer as accepted ;) thanks for the suggestion,i'll try(i saw it some time before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many alternatives for a graphical desktop. These involve

- Desktop environments (DEs) like GNOME or KDE. They offer a complete graphical interface, pre-loaded with the necessary apps like a file manager, web browser, etc. They are usually very resource consuming, and this can reduce the battery lifetime due to the higher CPU usage. If GNOME3 is performing poor on you machine, and you still want a complete DE, there are lighter alternatives as well: [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) or [XFCE](http://xfce.org/) are the most common ones.
- If you want something even lighter, then a window manager (WM) is the way to go. They only handle window management (resizing, maximizing, drawing a border, etc.), which means that you have to build the environment from scratch - you have to download each application, configure the theme, etc. There are several WMs available, I think [Openbox](http://openbox.org/) is a good one to start, but there are more advanced ones as well, see the [Wikipedia comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers) and [this guide](http://www.engadget.com/2012/10/30/how-to-picking-a-window-manager-linux/) for some ideas.

I would recommend going for a lighter DE, I personally prefer XFCE, but it's just a matter of personal taste. If you're still not satisfied with the results (resource usage, battery life), then you can't avoid using a window manager, which is fun if you enjoy configuring and tweaking your desktop. They offers very flexible configuration through config files.

Comment: i will try Enlightenment,but i will mark your answer as accepted anyway for the effort of writing :)

Comment: Well, `Enlightenment` is another nice alternative I didn't think of. It's low on resources and provides a nice desktop. Have fun with it!